# Set restriction on user by country for language translation content

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

How do I restrict individual user by country to see a restricted list of languages 
in the [Internationalization](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module? For example, I would like to restrict users from China, to see only Chinese translations.

I'm trying to get the country by `global $user;` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Translation Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n_access) module.

This module provides per-language access control for creating and updating nodes by adding a list of checkboxes for each available language to the user add/edit form (only visible to users with 'administer users' permission).